# Wolfram alpha integral

Tags: integration, wolfram-alpha

I want to evaluate the following integral in woflram alpha

int[x e^(-lambda*(x-v)),{x,v,infinity} ]

It doesn't work for some reason. It does work when instead of v, I put a number.

For example this works:

int[x e^(-lambda*(x-1)),{x,1,infinity} ]

Essentially there is no difference between the two.

Does someone know?

Comment: The problem is that wolfram alpha, does not know wheter $\lamba$ and are positive numbers. If lambda is negative the integral diverges. The problem is not with the limits, but wolfram's inability to decipher expressions containing symbols.

Comment: Thanks. I thought this would do the trick but it didn't: int[x e^(-lambda*(x-v)),{x,v,infinity}, Assumptions-> {lambda>0,x>=v} ]

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

You are  more clever than Wolfram Alpha. So use your knowledge for your problem (only **you** know at least the sign of $\lambda$).

Since $$x e^{-\lambda  (x-v)}=e^{\lambda v} x e^{- \lambda x}$$ then $$I=\int_v^{\infty}x e^{-\lambda  (x-v)}dx=e^{\lambda v}\int_v^{\infty} x e^{- \lambda x}dx$$ Now, change variable $x=\frac y{\lambda}$. So $$I=\frac{e^{\lambda v}}{\lambda}\int_1^{\infty} y e^{- y}dy$$ Now, use Wolfram Alpha ... or, much better, compute the antiderivative (it is simple).

Answer (score 0):

*Mathematica* works just fine:

```
Integrate[x Exp[-L (x - v)], {x, v, Infinity}]
```

gives the output

```
ConditionalExpression[(1 + L v)/L^2, Re[L] > 0]
```

We can also do the integral manually:  with the choice $u = \lambda(x-v)$, $du = \lambda \, dx$, we obtain $$\begin{align*} \int_{x=v}^\infty x e^{-\lambda(x-v)} \, dx &= \int_{u=0}^\infty \frac{1}{\lambda} \left(\frac{u}{\lambda} + v\right) e^{-u} \, du \\ &= \frac{1}{\lambda^2} \int_{u=0}^\infty u e^{-u} \, du + \frac{v}{\lambda} \int_{u=0}^\infty e^{-u} \, du \\ &= \frac{1 + \lambda v}{\lambda^2}, \end{align*}$$ as claimed.  For real-valued $\lambda$, this requires $ \lambda > 0$:  if $\lambda \le 0$, the integral fails to converge.